# Trouble editing the ip adress in the security group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can 't update the ip address on aws. I did everything: I deleted and created  the rule, I went in EC2 > Elastic IP addresses in vain. I deleted my database and created another one, and the ip address is still there.

But each time I try to create a rule and modify the ip address, I just can't do anything (delete modify :/).

Please help....

Below you can see a screen shot.

[image: Here is the aws screenshot from my account]

Comment: Maybe you have no permissions to change anything? You are the admin or a power user in the account?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't update the ip address"? If you change `My IP` to `Custom`, can you enter an IP address? If not, please tell us specifically what you are trying to do and what specific problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments helped figure out what I was doing wrong. I was

selecting the My IP in stead of just selecting Custom

0.0.0.0/0 ( to allow the connection of the Database with pg

admin4 on my local server) and just adding the ip address.

Thank you a lot, I can move on. :)